# Shell function does not return values greater than 255

Tags: linux, shell

```
   sum()
  {
     return $(($1+$2))

  }

   read a b
   sum $a $b
   echo $?
```

when we pass the value for a=255 and for b=36 the ans will be 35 why?

Comment: Which shell is it?

Comment: that is the design of all shell's return value. it will only return 0-255 (a small int). It is meant to return status values, rather than calculations. You'll find that the returned value is `mod 255`. I didn't downvote ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: @RhinoDevel bash shell

Comment: See here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/084

Answer (score 1):

you are asking the shell to return the value.

The return value cannot be anything more than 255.

so when you add a=255 and b=36

```
 a + b = 255 + 36 = 291
```

but since it can only return a value from 0-255.

you subtract

```
result - return value = 291 - 256 (i.e the return value from 0-255) = 35.
```

hence your return value of 35.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody pointed out, shell function cannot return a value greater that 255.

The common way to get values out of functions is to store them in a variable like so:

```
#! /bin/sh

sum() {
    local __res=$3
    local res=$(($1 + $2))
    eval $__res="'$res'"
}


sum 25000 5000 total

echo $total
```